# How to give a ngrx reducer/ action a value to set the state to?

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, reducers

I'm using Angular ngrx for the first time and I'm trying to replace all the @Input()s and @Output()s in my 'standard beginner-project' by it. Incrementing and Decrementing the state is simple, but I wonder how I can give the set Action a specific value to set the state to.

```
const _dividerReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(increment, (state) => state + 1),
  on(decrement, (state) => state - 1),
  on(set, (state) => initialState)
);
```

I have tried something like this so far at my actions:

```
import { createAction } from "@ngrx/store";
export const set = (newValue:number) => createAction("[Divider Component] Set", { newValue });
```

But that is obviously not the way it works - even if I saw that the second argument in createAction() is the config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue is in the reducer file. You are resetting the state to the initial value on the action set, i.e.  on(set, (state) => initialState).

The reducer for the set action should look something like below:

```
export interface IDividerState {
 value:number;
}

export const initialState: IDividerState = {
 value: 0
}

const _dividerReducer = createReducer(
initialState,
on(increment, (state) => state + 1),
on(decrement, (state) => state - 1),
on(set, (state, {payload}) => ({
value: payload
}));
```

Then your action for Set should have the payload which is the value you want to set:

```
import { createAction, props } from "@ngrx/store";

export const set = createAction(
  "[Divider Component] Set",
  props<{ payload: number }>()
);
```

Comment: This did not work directly but I got it working with ```on(set, (state, props) => props.payload)``` - thanks